# Ожидание ответа пользователя ( Python, discord.py )

Tags: discord.py

Интересует есть-ли функция в discord.py ожидания ответа пользователя, т.е. при использовании slash команды должен быть ответ, по типу: Как дела? и пользователь должен написать ответ, который код сможет прочитать ( без время ожидания )

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for):

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def command(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext) -> None:
    def check_func(message: discord.Message) -> bool:
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.content.lower() == 'hello'
    
    await ctx.respond('Send "Hello"')

    user_message: discord.Message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check_func, timeout=None)
    await user_message.reply(f'Hello, {user_message.author.mention}!')
```

Обратите внимание, бот реагирует только на того, кто вызвал команду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]